# Rmarkdown pdf report generate in different order after upgrading R3.5 to R4.2

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, ggpubr, tinytex

````
--- title:  "*********************" subtitle: <h1>*************</h1> date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B, %d %Y')\`"
header-includes:

- \\usepackage{makecell}
- \\usepackage{trimspaces}
- \\usepackage{environ}
- \\usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \\usepackage{threeparttable}
- \\usepackage{varwidth}
- \\usepackage{tabu}
- \\usepackage{pdflscape}
- \\usepackage{colortbl}
- \\usepackage{wrapfig}
- \\usepackage{multirow}
- \\usepackage{float}
- \\usepackage{xcolor}
- \\usepackage{titling}
- \\usepackage{array}
- \\pretitle{\\begin{center}\\Large\\includegraphics\[width=4cm\]{logo.png}\\\[\\bigskipamount\]}
- \\posttitle{\\end{center}}
- \\usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \\pagestyle{fancy}
- \\fancyhf{}
- \\rhead{\\includegraphics\[width = .05\\textwidth\]{bayer_logo.png}}
- \\fancyhead\[CO,CE\]{\\textcolor{red}{\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*}}
- "\\setlength{\\headheight}{30pt}"
- "\\addtolength{\\topmargin}{-18pt}"
  output: pdf_document
  always_allow_html: yes
  mainfont: Arial
  fontsize: 12pt
  toc: false
  indent: true
  geometry: margin=0.7in

---

\\definecolor{table1}{HTML}{D9DFE1}
\\definecolor{table2}{HTML}{C5DDEC}
\\definecolor{table3}{HTML}{81CFEB}
\\definecolor{table4}{HTML}{3E6AE1}
\\definecolor{table5}{HTML}{3100F5}
\\definecolor{myblue3}{HTML}{DAE5F9}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = '')
library(tinytex)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) 
library(bit64)
library(ggplot2)
library(xtable)
library(gridExtra)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)
library(aws.s3)
options(scipen=999)
````

I tried to downgrade the package version but it says that this package is not available for this version of R. I tried running the same Rmd file R3.5 and it is generating perfect report. Kindly suggest me some ways to tackle this issue. There is some package who is creating a problem

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  I see no output generated by your code snippet. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.